# $F, G$ partitions of A. show $F*G$ = ${\{t | t\in X, t\in Y\}}$ - where $X\in F$, and $Y \in G$

Tags: group-theory, integer-partitions

> $F, G$ are partitions of the group A. How can one show that $F*G$ is also a partition of $A$ in a way that $$F*G = \{t | t\in X, t\in Y\}$$ where $X\in F$, and $Y \in G$

Comment: Something is wrong with your definition of $F*G$. As written, it is not a partition of $G$, instead it is just the single set $X \cap Y$, for a fixed choice of $X \in F$ and $Y \in G$.

Answer (score 1):

Show it by hand:

1. Show that every point of $A$ appears in a set of $F * G$.
2. Show that no point of $A$ appears in more than one set of $F * G$.

First, you need to understand the definition of $F*G$, maybe write it down correctly (what you gave above is something like the idea, not the formal definition).

Comment: First of all thank you. Could you go into more details of how do I show points $1$, $2$ you mentioned?

Comment: If you understand the definition of $F*G$, there are not much more details; each step takes about half a line. So if you struggle, you might want to figure out your definition first.

Comment: By proving $1$, $2$, this proves the statement?

Comment: +1, if only for the mention that "what (the OP) gave above is something like the idea, not the formal definition" (a crucial piece of information which, I am afraid, might be somewhat lost on the OP, until now...).